# Hibernate: @OneToOne proper data extract

Tags: java, hibernate

Please help me with the following problem.

Class Person:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "person_id")
private int person_id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "person")
private PersonSocialAccount socialAccount;
```

Class PersonSocialAccount:

```
@Id
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false)
private Person person;

@Column(name = "providerId")
private String providerId;
```

When I'm using:

```
session.get(PersonSocialAccount.class, id);
```

Everything is fine, PersonSocialAccount contains reference to not null Person object.

But what should I do, if I want to find PersonSocialAccount by providerId?

When I'm trying to use something like :

```
(PersonSocialAccount) session.createQuery("from PersonSocialAccount where providerId = 125125").getSingleResult();
```

It returns PersonSocialAccount but with null Person object.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: why use `@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false)` instead of `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "socialAccount")`?

Comment: What's the difference?
Why should it be mapped by itself?

Comment: look at what you did in person class and do the same in PersonSocialAccount

Comment: That helped! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I changed my PersonSocialAccount to this:

```
@Id
@Column(name="person_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
@GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters={@Parameter(name="property", value="person")})
private int person_id;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Person person;
```